# Whats missing in this regex validation?

Tags: javascript, regex

Whats wrong with this regular expression?

```
^[a-zA-Z,\d,\&,\#,\-,\(,\']{3,15}$
```

Valid input is `alphanumeric`, `space`, `#`, `&`, `'`,  , `-`  with max and minimum length of 3 and 15 respectively.

when I enter the following valid input, it fails:

```
MT90#&' ABCD
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed space `\s`, and no need to use `,` in char set.

This will be ok:

```
/^[a-zA-Z\d\s&#-\(']{3,15}$/
```

***Update:***
`\s` will match on all whitespace (including tabs and line breaks as well as spaces), if you want just space, change to :

```
/^[a-zA-Z\d &#-\(']{3,15}$/
```

Comment: `\s` will match on *all* whitespace (including tabs and line breaks as well as spaces) which is not technically what the question asked.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need comma separators and you don't need to escape all those characters:

```
^[a-zA-Z\d\s&#-\(']{3,15}$
```

Comment: Hi Dawood, isnt the \d is for digits?

Comment: You're right, but you don't need comma separators and you don't need to escape &, # and '.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a space.  Try this: `[a-zA-Z\d\&\#\-\(\' ]{3,15}$`

Answer (score 0):

You only need to escape the following characters:

```
[ \ ^ $ . | ? * + ( )
```

You also don't need to have `','` between you characters in the set.
if you use `\s` in you regex, it will cover `space`, `tab` and `line breaks`.

Answer (score -1):

```
^[a-zA-Z\d\&\#\-\(\'\ ]{3,15}$
```

remove the commas and you're good to go